# Docker-compose syntax

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

```
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ]; \
        then npm install; \
        else npm install --only=production: \
        fi
```

When I try to run this code, I get that error message:

How can I fix that error?

```
 => ERROR [4/5] RUN if [ "development" = "development" ];         then npm install;         else npm install --only=production:         fi   
0.3s
------
 > [4/5] RUN if [ "development" = "development" ];         then npm install;         else npm install --only=production:         fi:
#8 0.291 /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting "fi")
------ executor failed running [/bin/sh -c if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ];         then npm install;         else npm install
--only=production:         fi]: exit code: 2 ERROR: Service 'node-app' failed to build : Build failed
```

Comment: Please read: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0):

On the `else` line, there's a colon after `--only=production`, but I think you meant to use a semicolon instead:

```bash
RUN if [ "$NODE_ENV" = "development" ]; \
        then npm install; \
        else npm install --only=production; \
        fi
```

Comment: oh, thanks. I just realized that. my brain slowed down due to fatigue